# comparison operator function in angularjs

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

i am new to angularjs platform, i am facing problem to solve a small task given by my employer. i hope someone can help me.

i have a set of employees table, i need to use a comparison operators in ng-option then a number field to put numbers to get the results. ( for example if the user select greater than from the ng-option and put '50' in the text field the result should filter the age greater than 50 from the data table. can anyone help pls!!

this is what i tried

```
$scope.operators = [
            {
                field: "gt"
                title: ">"
                }
                , {
                field: "lt"
                title: "<"
                }
                , {
                field: "et"
                title: "="
                }
             ];
        $scope.selected = $scope.operators[0];
        app.filter('priceGreaterThan', function () {
            return function (input, price) {
                var output = [];
                if (isNaN(price)) {
                    output = input;
                }
                else {
                    angular.forEach(input, function (item) {
                        if (item.redemptions > price) {
                            output.push(item)
                        }
                    });
                }
                return output;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Naren. in my function i don't know how to bring the selected value from the ng-option. this was my question

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use the filter to do all the three operations! Please refer to the below sample code.

Your filter works great, I added and `if else` condition for doing the different operations, also created a table for showing the output, so instead of passing the price alone to the filter, I am passing an object (`{price: price, operator: selected.field}`) which is then used inside the filter for getting the price and the operator, please check my code and let me know if there are any issues.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
    name: 1,
    redemptions: 100
  }, {
    name: 1,
    redemptions: 150
  }, {
    name: 1,
    redemptions: 200
  }, {
    name: 1,
    redemptions: 50
  }, {
    name: 1,
    redemptions: 1
  }, {
    name: 1,
    redemptions: 10
  }]
  $scope.operators = [{
    field: "gt",
    title: ">"
  }, {
    field: "lt",
    title: "<"
  }, {
    field: "et",
    title: "="
  }];
  $scope.selected = $scope.operators[0];
});

app.filter('priceGreaterThan', function() {
  return function(input, params) {
    var output = [];
    if (isNaN(params.price)) {
      output = input;
    } else {
      angular.forEach(input, function(item) {
        if (params.operator === "gt") {
          if (item.redemptions > params.price) {
            output.push(item);
          }
        } else if (params.operator === "lt") {
          if (item.redemptions < params.price) {
            output.push(item);
          }
        } else {
          if (item.redemptions == params.price) {
            output.push(item);
          }
        }
      });
    }
    return output;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
  <input type="text" ng-model="price">
  <select name="operator" id="test" ng-model="selected" ng-options="x as x.title for x in operators"></select>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Redemptions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="j in data | priceGreaterThan: {price: price, operator: selected.field}">
      <td>{{j.name}}</td>
      <td>{{j.redemptions}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```